# Disable session save in doom emacs

Tags: emacs

Noob question from a noob making the switch from vim to doom emacs: How can I get doom emacs *not* to remember a given file I was editing? For example, if I edit a file, quit out of doom and relaunch it, then go back to editing the same file, if I do an undo, the editor remembers the history and begins to undo the operations I performed in the previous session. I want this not to happen.

I have `(desktop-save-mode -1)` in my init file, have appended `--no-desktop` when launching emacs from the terminal, and used M-x to disable session-save. No luck. What should I do to obtain the result I want?